# How difficult is this piece of music (electric guitar)?

Tags: electric-guitar, skill-level

Listening to this [piece of music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khjvSzKF0vc&t=132) (from 2:12), "Running from Evil" (by Bobby Prince), and being a total novice, I was wondering how difficult it is to play on the guitar.

[Another version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVn6C6uiFo0&t=105) that seems also amazingly difficult.

How would you rate the level of difficulty, say from 1 (easy) to 5 (top level)?

*Note*: this is **not** an opinion-based question. I'm simply amazed at the pace of the music, observing the fingers moving at the speed of light, or almost... ; seen from my level (= zero) that sounds hyper-difficult, but I'd like to hear what the expert has to say...

Comment: Hi e2-e4 and welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this is an opinionated question as there is no universal way to judge difficulty so any answer is going to be based on the user's perception of the piece making every answer equally valid.

Comment: The question would be better if you asked for a list of prerequisites and skills that are needed to play that example. It would be interesting to see how people divide areas to learn, for example right-hand vs left-hand, sight reading, playing to a click, picking, hand synchronization, hand independence etc. What kind of a difficulty hierarchy is there in each area, and are there dependencies between skills. Maybe that would still be too broad, but a skilled Stack Exchange expert might be able to construct a proper question. ;)

Comment: Would editing question and asking to rate the piece against a grade make it non opinion based? @Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

185 BPM, alternate picking between 2 strings nonstop. So many notes.

I think it is 3. Feels like the beginning of Advanced level

Comment: Wow! What would you say is 5? Van Halen? Slash? Gilmour?...

Comment: @e2-e4 your example isn't particularly fast, and it seems to be a pre-written sequence, which can be learned through mechanical repetition. Things get more advanced when you make it up it on the spot as you're playing! Check out stuff like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dloRBA3Z1W4&t=132s

Comment: "there are simply too many notes" :-)